# Error NaN, al querer sacar los decimales jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Intento sacar los decimales o al menos solo dejarle dos, y no lo estoy pudiendo lograr.
Poseo un codigo que es el siguiente

```
Cifra=  new Intl.NumberFormat("es-AR").format(parseInt($('#PInicio').val())+ (parseInt($('#PBono').val())/12); //esto me arroja 560.947,1588 (4 decimales) 
Valor = Math.trunc(Cifra);
$('#Fee').val(Valor);// me arroja NaN
```

Si no hago la operacion Math.trunc El campo Fee me muestra el numero con los 4 decimales sin el error NaN.
No se q estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usando la opción `maximumFractionDigits` podes formatear con 2 decimales o sin decimales. para usar `Math.trunc` el número tiene que estar en formato javascript ( el `NumberFormat("es-AR")` es lo que genera el Not a Number )

```js
valor = 560947.1588

Cifra = new Intl.NumberFormat( "es-AR", { maximumFractionDigits: 0 } ).format( valor );

OtraCifra = new Intl.NumberFormat( "es-AR", { maximumFractionDigits: 2 } ).format( valor );

console.log( valor, Cifra, OtraCifra )

// para usar trunc con un formato no javascript:
valor = "560.947,1588"
console.log( valor, 
  Math.trunc( 
    parseFloat( 
      valor
        .replace(".", "") // miles
        .replace(",", ".") // decimales
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Genial MUCHAS GRACIASSSSSSS